# Can I delete a CSS file with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a website with 1 html and a lot of CSSs, but they keep overwriting eachother.
How can I delete a CSS file of the HTML from the JavaScript? For they don't overwrite anymore.

Comment: Can you please include your code? It'd be more easy for us to understand your question.

Comment: Better organize your CSS styles so they don’t conflict, and/or don’t include unnecessary styles in the HTML to begin with‽ Removing styles at runtime seems like the worst bandaid to a generally unorganized situation.

Comment: Do you want to delete css code or complete css file? because if you are making a site then you can just avoid to use any css file

Comment: A simple answer to your question: You cannot delete css file with javascript unless its server side javascript i.e NODE. you can remove the styles with the javascript although

Answer (score 2):

Overwriting CSS? You probably mean one css file overwrites the styles of your other CSS files. Okay, now that's a problem and the right way to resolve it is by removing the culprit styles or css files manually.

You can't delete CSS files through Javascript on the browser because that's a client-side scripting language.

You can remove css styles applied on your html elements, yes; but delete CSS Files? No, that can't be done.

I'd say, refocus on cleaning the site up.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace or remove that CSS file via JavaScript as follows:

```js
// replace
document.querySelector("link[rel='styleSheet']").setAttribute("href", "anotherStyle.css")

// remove
document.querySelector("link[rel='styleSheet']").removeAttribute("href")
```

You can also be more specific while selecting the `link` tag using `href` attribute instead of `rel` as follows:

```js
// replace
document.querySelector("link[href='style.css']").setAttribute("href", "anotherStyle.css")

// remove
document.querySelector("link[href='style.css']").removeAttribute("href")
```